# How to find my specific button over window?

Tags: ipad, uibutton

I have created by custom UIButton for iPad application.

Now for specific reasons, I want to hide those buttons. To do that I am using following code:

```
NSMutableArray *viewArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Get all the windows
    for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows])
    {
      // check for main screen
      if (![window respondsToSelector:@selector(screen)] ||
          [window screen] == [UIScreen mainScreen])
      {

        // check for all the subviews available in window
        for (UIView * view in [window subviews]) {

          // check whether it supports this method
          if ([view respondsToSelector:@selector(isKindOfClass:)]) {

            // type cast to button
            //          UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)view;

            // if its type of my custom button class
            if ([[view class] isKindOfClass:[DINNextLTProBoldButton class]]) {

              // hide view and add to array
              [view setHidden:YES];
              [viewArray addObject:view];
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

But I am not able to get my custom buttons in this array. It stays empty only even thought the view which is being appeared on window/screen have those buttons.

Where I am going wrong? Please guide me.

Comment: When creating your buttons assign them a tag, you can then use that tag to hide/show the button as needed.

Comment: you're only going 2 levels down in the view hierarchy, you need to loop through the subviews recursively

Comment: But how to fetch multiple buttons for that, as this method viewWithTag provides only one view from window, where as in my application those button counts are getting changed as per my view requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this (untested, but it gives the basic idea)

```
- (void)hideViewOfClass:(Class)clazz inHeirarchyOfView:(UIView *)view
{
    for (UIView *subview in [view subviews])
    {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:clazz])
            subview.hidden = YES;
        else 
            [self hideViewOfClass:clazz inHeirarchyOfView:subview];
    }
}
```

call this function at first like:

```
for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows])
    [self hideViewOfClass:[DINNextLTProBoldButton class] inHeirarchyOfView:window];
```